# Issue with Drag and Drop element in Selenium Web driver with Java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In left pane there are some widgets the below code gives some idea about how the widgets are organized....

```html
<div id="sites-widgets-1375699547529" class="sites-widget-container tab-content-div frog-touch-scroll active">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="image draggable" data-content="file/widget/0141D9112001BD9824CA7FB813F3CF04088C02AC50F154FA/icon.png" data-uuid="0141D9112001BD9824CA7FB813F3CF04088C02AC50F154FA" style="background-image:url(file/widget/0141D9112001BD9824CA7FB813F3CF04088C02AC50F154FA/icon.png);"/>
<div class="ui-editor-box-label">Text Activity</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
<div class="ui-editor-box">
</div>
```

I want to drag and drop a widget to the container provided in the same web page. the code for the container is given below

```html
<div class="sites-layout-one-one">
<div style="clear:both;"/>
<div class="bucket ui-sortable edit" data-order="1" data-attr="bucket"/>
<div style="clear:both;"/>
</div>
```

I'm trying to drag and drop the widget in to the container, but i cant able to do this, the code that i wrote is below

```c#
WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sites-widget-container tab-content-div frog-touch-scroll active']/div[@class='ui-editor-box'][1]"));

WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sites-layout-one-one']"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragElement)
                    .moveToElement(dropElement)
                    .release(dropElement)
                    .build();
                      dragAndDrop.perform();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Please help me to sort out this...

Thanks in Advance

Shiva..

Comment: I had the same problem. After extensive research on SO and the net, I think this is a Selenium bug. I filed a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315&thanks=6315&ts=1380031813

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built in dragAndDrop action to handle this for you:

```java
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.dragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement).perform();
```

The API documentation is located here, which shows the usage for the dragAndDrop action:

> http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: This is not working, even i tried with this one previously, it is not working for me, don't know what's wrong... in my code..

Comment: I would double check to make sure your dragElement and dropElement are the correct elements that are draggable.